# Replace a BlockingQueue + daemon thread with an Executor

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, queue

I have a `BlockingQueue` with tasks, and a single daemon thread executing them:

```java
public class TaskManager {

  private final BlockingQueue<Task> taskQueue;

  public TaskManager() {
    this.taskQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(5); //Max 5 tasks waiting
    Thread taskRunner = new Thread(this::runTask);
    taskRunner.setDaemon(true); //Infinite loop inside shouldn't prevent JVM shutdown
    taskRunner.start();
  }

  //Called async
  public void enqueueTask(Task task) {
    boolean added = false;
    try {
        added = taskQueue.offer(task, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {/*no-op*/}
    if (!added) {
        publishEvent(new Fail(task)); //Async notify the client their task won't run
    }
  }

  //Also called async
  public void dequeueTask(Task task) {
    this.taskQueue.remove(task);
  }

  void runTask() {
    while (true) {
      try {
        Task task = taskQueue.take(); //Blocks indefinitely
        doStuff(task);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          //Can only be a spurious interruption. Ignore.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Doesn't seem too special. But. It feels like I'm reinventing the wheel by managing the queue and the daemon myself. I'd expect this to be easily doable with an `Executor(Service)` instead. I could have a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with 1 thread, give it a bounded queue. It exposes a `remove` method for me to dequeue tasks. But it seems there's no way to timeout if enqueuing takes too long (5s timeout on `taskQueue.offer()` in my example).

Is what I'm doing already legit and I'm just overthinking? If not, can I replace this with an `Executor` and how?

Comment: Maybe try [`Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)).

Comment: Can you redesign your software so that `Task` is a `Runnable` rather than requiring the executor to call `doStuff(task);`?

Comment: @Holger Yes. I'm only missing a way to get the same behavior I have with `taskQueue.offer(task, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`, I think...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s important to understand that [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) does never wait for the queue to become “not full”. It uses [`offer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#offer(E)) which immediately returns `false` if the capacity is exhausted and if that happens and the configured maximum thread size has been reached, the executor will call the [`RejectedExecutionHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/RejectedExecutionHandler.html).

So, you can specify a maximum thread count of one and this [`RejectedExecutionHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/RejectedExecutionHandler.html):

```java
RejectedExecutionHandler tryForFiveSecs = (r, es) -> {
    boolean added = false;
    try {
        BlockingQueue<Runnable> taskQueue = ((ThreadPoolExecutor)es).getQueue();
        added = taskQueue.offer(r, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {/*no-op*/}
    if(!added) {
        //assuming the Runnable and "Task" are interchangeable
        publishEvent(new Fail(r));
    }
};
```

Using the constructor [`ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue, ThreadFactory threadFactory, RejectedExecutionHandler handler)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,int,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue,java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory,java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionHandler)).

Note that this covers uses of `execute` which is sufficient for your existing workflows. If you start using `submit` and the returned futures, you have to consider that the futures returned for failed jobs will never finish. Unless, you extend the handler, e.g.:

```java
RejectedExecutionHandler tryForFiveSecs = (r, es) -> {
    boolean added = false;
    try {
        BlockingQueue<Runnable> taskQueue = ((ThreadPoolExecutor)es).getQueue();
        added = taskQueue.offer(r, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {/*no-op*/}
    if(!added) {
        //assuming the Runnable and "Task" are interchangeable
        publishEvent(new Fail(r));
        if(r instanceof Future<?> f) f.cancel(false);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't occur to me to use RejectedExecutionHandler to retry. Btw do you think my original approach was correct (in the sense of behavior)?

Comment: Looked ok to me. The only thing I noticed was that the invocation of `doStuff` was not surrounded by a catch-all so if an uncaught exception occurs, the background thread would terminate thus, stop processing tasks.